# My Code displays nothing but an empty page (The written text isn't up)

Tags: html

I wrote this as a beginning to display it shows hey but doesn't display the text between title's tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr" class=" "><head>
<title>Staff Roster - Information - Next Generation Gaming</title>
</head><body>hey</body></html>
```

I'm a newbie btw

Comment: That html is not valid.. look at `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: There's no content to display

Comment: Please, do invest some time in learning the basics of html first... There are plenty of resources available online.

Comment: any help to be given ?

Comment: _any help to be given ?..._ Have you read our comments at all?

Answer (score 1):

The text between the  tags will not display on your web page, but you can see it show on your browser tab. Moreover, everything in the  tags can only display on your web page that is why you can only see the text "hey" .